# How to add objects named obj1, obj2, obj3, ... to NSMutableArray in for loop

Tags: ios, objective-c, loops, nsmutablearray

Is there better way for

```
_studentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:student0, student1, student2, student3, student4, student5, student6, student7, student8, student9, student10, student11, student12, student13, student14, student15, student16, student17, student18, student19, nil];
```

using FOR loop?

Comment: yes loop you can use

Comment: It depend from where student objects came from...

Comment: Your real problem is that you have 20 variables apparently. Which seems to indicate that you are in trouble if there are only 19 students, and in seriously bad trouble if there are 21 students. Look at how you got these 20 variables; this is seriously strange.

Comment: @gnasher729 I doubt these are received separately from a library call or coworker's method, so he probably declared and initialized all 20 variables "by hand". The correct solution then is to create an empty array and use [array addObject:[[Student alloc] initWith...]] directly or using a single intermediate variable 'Student *s' or whatever type of student value is.

Comment: Please show how you get all these student values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others have pointed out, it's probably best to not create 20 different objects in uniquely named variables (student0, student1, student2, etc) in the first place. Better to create them in an array in the first place, as others have pointed out.

If you MUST deal with lots of instance variables like that, you should be able to use valueForKey to find them all:

```
_studentArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: 20];
for (int i=0; i< 20; i++)
{
  NSString *keyName = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"student%d", i];
  id aStudentVar = [self objectForKey: keyName];
  _studentArray[i] = aStudentVar;
}
```

I haven't tested this, but it should work. Again, though, having that many sequentially named instance variables is a bad "[**code smell**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell)". There is almost certainly a better way to do whatever it is you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the source from where and at a time how many objects you are getting

if you are getting all the object in a go you can add as above or by using a for loop to add individual objects.

If you are getting a single object at a time add it and add other objects as well.

Answer (score 0):

It depends where the student objects came from, how they were created etc. But I think you should re-think your code to NOT have a reference for each student like you did. Just think about how hard would it be if facebook had done the same as you did to refere to each user?

If you are creating the student objects by yourself, try an approach like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {


    _studentArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {

        Student *student = [[Student alloc] init];
        [_studentArray addObject:student];
    }

    //At this point you will have the same that you did.

    //To access the 2nd student for example, you could do
    Student *theSecond = _studentArray[1]; //(because array index starts from 0)
    theSecond.name = @"Peter";
}
```

or if you want to create and add to `_studentsArray` at the same time:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    _studentArray = [NSMutableArray new];

    [self registerStudentWithName:@"Peter"];
    [self registerStudentWithName:@"John"];
    //and so on...

    Student *firstStudent = _studentArray[0];
    NSLog(@"%@", firstStudent.name); //Prints Peter
}

- (void)registerStudentWithName:(NSString *)name {

    Student *student = [[Student alloc] init];
    student.name = name;
    [_studentArray addObject:student];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Its very simple, all you have to do is start for loop for some count.

```
for(int i=0;i<20;i++) { 
    NSString *obj = [[NSString alloc]init];
    [_studentArray addObject:obj]; 
}
```